# Finding missing ampersands (&) in function signatures?

Tags: c++

There is a large body of code where some values could & should be const reference instead of a copy. Is there any tool that helps search for such "missing ampersands" in the code to help prevent unneeded copies that slow down the process considerably?

Comment: Not really, as in some places you *want* to pass by value instead of pass by reference, and it's impossible for a tool to know your intentions (it's not a mind-reader). It might be possible if you have a small list of types that should *always* be passed by reference, but there's no way to make a generic tool. Also note that if you fiddle with the copy-constructor, you also have to think about all other places a copy-constructor is used (like variable definitions or *returning* by vale and possible other places).

Comment: Searching for function calls without a ampersand can probably be done with a regex, but I'm not good enough at that to provide it ;-)

Comment: If you are specifically looking for const references it shouldn't be too hard for a tool to detect situations where a parameter is never written to and hence could be const and passed by ref. I'm fairly sure that for example resharper does similarly complex code analysis in C# (although the specific problem here doesn't occur in C# ;-)).

Comment: Can be done with lib clang (or probably with C-tag and regex).

Comment: @kebs: Forget it. Parsing C++ with a regex is flat out impossible.

Comment: Ended up going function by function, checking and asking myself if a type represents a large collection of data and if it's not a const ref yet. This is dangerous with large collections of data as copying is too taxing for performance and ampersands are easy to overlook. In a way my personal feeling is that the none-C way of having the default be a ref is actually more forgiving to fledglings and older people who just don't like checking code that works perfectly for a performance leak.

Answer (score 2):

Put `break point` in the `copy constructor` for the objects that are copied and debug.

Comment: Might give a lot of false positives, for example in variable definitions with copy-initialization, or for functions returning by value.

Comment: Sure, it is just a quick way. BTW if optimization is on, many of those copies will be dismissed

Comment: Wow!  A run-time check seems a much poorer approach than compile-time.

Comment: Common man it is a free dummy approach with no need to external tools. it does not deserve that much critics :D

Comment: "_Put break point in the copy constructor for the objects that are copied and debug._" and then be sure your program goes to every possible case in your debug session....
I would go making copy ctor private, or deleted, or better [deprecated](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/marking-deprecated-c++14.html) if your compiler allows it, and then check every actual use of copy ctor and evaluate if the copy can be replaced with a const reference
agree with @JoachimPileborg, false positives to handle anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a smart way, you can make the copy ctor of the class `deleted`, and confirm all the compile errors.

Comment: Might give a lot of false positives, for example in variable definitions with copy-initialization, or for functions returning by value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How many of the false positives would go away if you deleted the copy-constructor, but left the move-constructor in place?  (Wouldn't spot pass-by-value calls with an argument that was a temporary - but I think that's harmless anyway).

Comment: We actually never return by value. This is very smart imho. Some types that  represent a large collection of data should not be copied. It is just that your can look for ampersands and can't Ctrl+F for the lack of one.;)